# Error converting varchar to numeric

Tags: sql

I have an issue with my case statement. Here is an extract from my table structure:

```
total = decimal(9,2)
selfrec = decimal(9,2)
```

And here's the CASE statements that's giving me issues:

```
CASE
    WHEN Invoices.selfrec IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'Self Reconcilation: ' + Invoices.total + ' - ' + Invoices.selfrec + ' = ' + Invoices.total - Invoices.selfrec ELSE Invoices.total 
END AS 'total'
```

When selfrec is not null, it seems to try converting the strings such as 'Self Reconcilation:' to numeric, and obviously fails. Why is it doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: 122 questions and only 2 votes. Seriously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run this line:

```
select 'Self Reconcilation: ' + Invoices.total + ' - ' + Invoices.selfrec + ' = ' + Invoices.total - Invoices.selfrec
```

You'll get the error. You are trying to do an implicit conversion of a numeric value to a varchar.

Try the following. Varchar(12) should suffice for decimal (9,2) (Nine + two, and one for the '.')

```
select 'Self Reconcilation: ' + cast(Invoices.total as varchar(12)) + ' - ' + cast(Invoices.selfrec as varchar(12)) + ' = ' + cast(Invoices.total - Invoices.selfrec  as varchar(12))
```

Giving you:

```
CASE
    WHEN Invoices.selfrec IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 'Self Reconcilation: ' + cast(Invoices.total as varchar(12)) + ' - ' + cast(Invoices.selfrec as varchar(12)) + ' = ' + cast(Invoices.total - Invoices.selfrec as varchar(12))
    ELSE Invoices.total
END AS 'total'
```

Also, why not test for the NULL first. The else clause is effectively saying 'if not not null'. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are leaving it to infer a type based on a string and a numeric. Give it a hint:

```
ELSE CONVERT(varchar(30), Invoices.total)
```

Then it has the choices of varchar and varchar, so it *knows* this is varchar from the outset, and can't make any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks buddy, still have the issue though

Answer (score 3):

It's actually attempting to convert `' = '` etc to numeric in order to perfrom the numeric addition. You need to `CAST` the numeric to varchar first.